Apollo cache updateFragment and evict method seems to not work properly together
Let's say that in my app, I have a mutation that is converting one entity to another one. Let's call this mutation convertEntity.
this mutation returns the ID and type of the deleted entity and the ID, name, and type of the newly created one.
This is how I would describe my useConvertEntity hook and convertEntity mutation with cache update:
await convertEntity({
  variables: {
    entity,
  },
  update: (cache, res) => {
    if (!res.data) {
      return;
    }

    const typename = entity.fromType;
    const normalizedId = cache.identify({id: entity.id, __typename: typename});
    cache.evict({id: normalizedId});
    cache.gc();
  
    const parentNormalizedId = cache.identify({
      id: parentId,
      __typename: convertedParentType,
    });
    

      cache.updateFragment<ConvertEntityCacheUpdateFragment>(
        {
          id: parentNormalizedId,
          fragment: gql`
            fragment ConvertEntityCacheUpdate on SomeObject {
              id
              entitiesType1 {
                id
              }
              entitiesType2 {
                id
              }
              entitiesType3 {
                id
              }
            }
          `,
        },
        someObject => {
          if (!someObject?.id) {
            return someObject;
          }
          if (entity.to === entityType1) {
            return {
              ...someObject,
              entitiesType1: [
                ...someObject.entitiesType1, 
                {__typename: 'entityType1', id: res.data.convertEntity.id}],
            };
          }
          ... // some other logic
          }
          return someObject;
        },
      );
    }
  },
});

The issue that I'm facing here is that after when the entity is evicted from cache and cache.updateFragment is being used, some of the queries that use this evicted ID are trying to refetch the data. The outcome is that all those queries are failing bc there is no such ID anymore, bc the mutation is removing those entities from the BE.
When I'm leaving only cache.evict part everything is working ok, the entity is evicted and following queries are cancelled.
But if I'm using the updateFragment the dependant queries are trying to refetch with deleted ID.
I was trying many approaches like updateFragment / modify / evict from ROOT_QUERY etc but nothing worked.
The only solution that worked was to wrap the cache.updateFragment with setTimeout, and it was enough to set the delay to 0s - after when I did this everything is working correctly, but I'm bias about this solution, it feels like it is not right...
Can anyone explain to me why this is happening or why setTimeout worked?
I was trying to solve this by evicting the entity also from the ROOT_QUERY, but without any results, the issue was still there.
I also was trying to use cache.modify instead cache.updateFragment, no success here as well.
I was trying to use Promise.all(), no success also.
